# Pasar una función de JavaScript a un archivo externo

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar JavaScript y me gustaría saber cómo pasar una función declarada en un archivo HTML a un archivo externo de JavaScript y mandar a llamar la función desde éste. El ejemplo es el siguiente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function validaciion(){
   x=document.form
   txt=x.miInput.value
   if(txt>=1 && txt<=5){
    alert("Es correcto")
    return true
   }
   else{
    if (txt<1) alert("es menor que 1, debe estar entre 1 y 5")
    else if (txt>1) alert("es mayor que 5, debe estar entre 1 y 5")
    else alert("no es valido, debe estar entre 1 y 5")
    return false
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form" action="#" onsubmit="return validaciion()">
  introducir un numero entre 1 y 5: 
  <input type="text" name="miInput">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar valor">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poniendo la función en un archivo javascript y referenciándola en cada documento que la necesites. Es la solución más sensata. También puedes guardar en `localStorage` la función como texto y ejecutarla con eval en otro documento. Esto aparte de inseguro es innecesario si puedes hacer lo primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copia tal cual tienes la funcion **validaciion()** a un archivo javascript (por ejemplo: validaciones.js) y guárdalo en la misma carpeta donde tienes el archivo HTML. Para llamar a la función que esta en otro archivo solo basta con decirle en donde se encuentra

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validaciones.js">
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo tu respuesta, como no lo pensé antes, gracias :)